# Let A, B and C be sets. Prove that $A \times (B-C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$

Tags: proof-writing

Because of distributive properties we know this is true, but I am stuck on showing the proof. I know: Let $x\in A\times (B-C)$. This means $x\in\mathbb{A}$ and $x\in B$ but $x\ not in C$. Assume $x\in A$ then from here im not sure where to go.

Comment: I think you are confusing the [notation for the] cartesian product of sets, with the intersection of sets.

Answer (score 4):

You do not know this because of the "distributive property" because the distributive property is what you are being asked to prove.

Hint. $$x \in  A \times (B-C)$$
means $x$ is an 
*ordered pair* 
$(y,z)$ where $y \in A$ and $z \in B-C$.